# Duplicate keys in the JSON document overwrite each other

Tags: json, mongodb

Attempting to save the following JSON to MongoDB

```
{
  "EID":"1234367574",
  "DID": "0123456789",
  "Settings": {"Q":"12345678455kkkk"},
  "Settings": {"Q":"123---------45678455kkkk"}
}
```

result in saving the following instead

```
{
  "EID":"1234367574",
  "DID": "0123456789",
  "Settings": {"Q":"123---------45678455kkkk"}
}
```

I'm using C# and BsonDocument as data type.

Comment: This is how JSON works. You are not supposed to have the same key appear twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a json object keys are supposed to be unique. Check [http://www.json.org](http://www.json.org/):

> JSON is built on two structures:

> - A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is
>   realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
>   list, or associative array.
> - An ordered list of values. In most
>   languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

You have an example of the first structure. You may know that if you try to put a key twice in a hash table, for instance, the second value will overwrite the first one, exactly as you experience in your attempt. In other implementations, you may have an error thrown instead.

It looks like an embedded json array (second kind of structure) would be more suitable for your case: what about the following?

```
{
  "EID":"1234367574",
  "DID": "0123456789",
  "Settings": [{"Q":"12345678455kkkk"},{"Q":"123---------45678455kkkk"}]
}
```

**NOTE:**

It has been pointed out that [JSON spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) only says that names (keys) SHOULD be unique and does not say MUST.

This is true.

However, the [latest spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) indicates that without uniqueness you do not know what behaviour to expect:

> When the names within an object are not
> unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is
> unpredictable.  Many implementations report the last name/value pair
> only.  Other implementations report an error or fail to parse the
> object, and some implementations report all of the name/value pairs,
> including duplicates.

Comment: The JSON spec says "The names within an object SHOULD be unique.", which means it is "RECOMMENDED" (but NOT "REQUIRED"), that keys within a JSON document be unique. I noticed the text you quoted does not mention anything about the keys being unique. See: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt and https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8320 ; the latter link shows that MongoDB can store JSON documented with two or more values for the same key, although most tools will break in this circumstance, it is possible that any one of your MongoDB documents has more than one value for any key.

Comment: @Buttons840 You seem to be right, thanks. I will do some more research and come back to the answer

Comment: @Buttons840 The latest specification https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259 explains what happens when you do not have uniqueness (unpredicatble behaviour) . I'm updating the answer